# AmazonS3Encryption ignores EncryptionMaterials provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I'm experimenting with retrieving an encrypted object from S3 (put there by SES).

What I don't understand is no matter what paramater I provide to `KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider(x)` , the object is unencrypted & retrieved successfully.

Even providing a CMK that was not used by the encryption process works.

Without `withEncryptionMaterials(x)` it fails.

What is it that I misunderstand?

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsId, awsSecret);

CryptoConfiguration cryptoConf = new CryptoConfiguration()
           .withAwsKmsRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1.getName()));

AmazonS3Encryption s3Encryption = AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withCryptoConfiguration(cryptoConf)
            //.withEncryptionMaterials(new SimpleMaterialProvider())
            //.withEncryptionMaterials(new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider("aws/ses"))
            //.withEncryptionMaterials(new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider("ses-dev-emaildrop"))
            .build();

S3Object s3object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, s3ObjKey));
```